# How to Switch out Project DLLs & Versions While Using Nuget at Build

Tags: .net, git, dll, msbuild, nuget

We have C# solution with 10 projects all within Git. In order to accommodate multiple versions of one of the DLLs (primary 3rd party product), we have the same code duplicated among 4 branches.

A great solution would be to allow for us to define a parameter at build within TeamCity which would be used to determine group of DLLs to reference. This, in affect, would allow us to scale down to one master branch and an artifact labelled with the DLL version.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to add the DLL as a submodule.  You could then have each branch refer to different versions of the .DLL.

Comment: Our hopes are to move away from multiple branches since the old reason they exist is due to the 3rd party dependency DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had implemented the below solution for one of our project. It may work for you.

Since you have not specified how the 3rd party DLLS are referenced, I am assuming they are delivered as a nuget package which is then referenced and  included the packages.config

Steps

1. Add version parameter in TC build config and set a default value
2. Source downloaded from VCS by TC during build
3. Using file content replacer build feature in TC, replace the version to the specified value in packages.config or any other file
   refers to the version(to override default value - either run a
   custom build and specify the parameter value or have 4 different
   build configurations with the required version values for 3rd party packages)
4. Restore the nuget packages which should then get the correct packages before MSBuild.

Hope so this works for you

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Good to know that this solution worked for you as well :)

Comment: It will be! We've not implemented this yet but have confirmed this will work best for us. Thank you!